# Where is this parameter getting its value from?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, decorator

I have this code:
https://jsfiddle.net/toddmotto/qaqeapn6/
I'm wondering, where is the 'target' parameter getting its value from?
`function (target)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a decorated class

A Decorator is a special kind of declaration that can be attached to a class declaration, method, accessor, property, or parameter. Decorators use the form @expression, where expression must evaluate to a function that will be called at runtime with information about the decorated declaration.

Please refer https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: I get the idea. But what about the 'target' argument, how is the function getting the value for it?

Comment: Typescript will be compiled into javascript. That compiled code would call the function returned from Console method with the class that is decorated.

Comment: I got it, its a decorator factory, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

That is internal feature of Class Decorators.
ES2016 Decorators work on property descriptors and classes. They automatically get passed property names and the target object, as we’ll soon cover. Having access to the descriptor allows a decorator to do things like changing a property to use a getter, enabling behaviour that would otherwise be cumbersome such as automatically binding methods to the current instance on first access of a property.

You can read further information: https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841#.qj8979jae

Comment: Well fast checking the website you provided I found a similar behaviour where the superheroe function is getting its value from the argument passed 'true'. But how does the returned function get the value for 'target'. I understand that it could be called anything instead of target and it would still work. But how?